# What types of propulsion are used to adjust an orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver

What types of propulsion are used to adjust the orbit of an object such as a satellite, space station, supply vehicle?

I'm curious if they all use the same method to adjust their trajectory, or if there are a variety of approaches taken. I am just looking for a list so I can read up on the topic further.

Comment: I started trying to think of a list, but the best I could come up with was "pretty much all of them, probably minus nuclear".

Comment: Big engines and Small engines, Hydrolox and Kerolox and Bipropellant and Monopropellant, Hydrazine Thrusters and Hall thrusters, ion thrusters and other electrical propulsions of a great many styles and flavors. There's a test of solar electrolized-water-hydrolox out there! Even light pressure and electrodynamic torquers(which not only torque, but also apply a minute linear acceleration). And that's just to **start** with. I don't think there is a VASIMR plasma drive out there right now, but there sure were plans for it. The sky is (not) the limit!

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask "What types of propulsion are most commonly used to adjust the orbit of satellites?".. In which case the answer is more like: Hydrazine thrusters, and Hall-effect thrusters. With the latter gaining market very rapidly due to the Horde (a.k.a. the Starlink constellation) using Krypton Hall-effect thrusters, 1 each.(1844 to date, 42 000 planned)

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking: Yes, had I known the list was so lengthy, I would have limited it by asking for 'current' or 'commonly' used. I read about space exploration, but I am outside the industry, so I am often unaware of how big of a question I have. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @DanSorensen even limiting it to "current" would not shorten the list by methods, merely reduce the different models of devices in use. But for on-orbit satellites, just stationkeeping or slightly adjusting orbit, it's 90% hydrazine thrusters(where quick <1hour sometimes <1 minute thrusts are needed), or Hall Effect "ion" thrusters(where economy of fuel or power is important, and burn times reach days).

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking , your list is great. I also can't help singing it in my head to the tune of "My Favorite Things" from "The Sound of Music".

Comment: @Jason :) :D  Yes that sort of thing was intended, I'm glad it shone through even if faintly. I wanted to compose it to the rhyme of "Lions and Tigers and Bears, Oh My!", but could not get the metre right.

Comment: @DanSorensen You might want to take a peek at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_propulsion  .. but be prepared to be overwhelmed. The list comprises some 50 items, of which about half are in active use

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking : you have some good feedback in your comments. The list would be worthy of being formatted into an answer for easier reference for others. That said, the propulsion link you and SE - stop mentioned is good now that I know it exists. Thank you again. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much everything is on the table, as an orbital environment puts little restrictions on what can work. So for an extensive list, [wikipedia - spacecraft propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_propulsion#Table_of_methods) has a handy table. While most of them *can* be used, sort by technology readiness level for a more realistic view of what's available.

For most practical use cases outside mere technology demonstrations, there are:

- Simple cold gas thrusters.
- Chemical engines: monopropellants, bipropellants and solid fuel all used.
- Electric thrusters: electrostatic and Hall effect.

Common types of engines you will ***Not*** find in orbit:

- Jet engines, due to the lack of atmosphere, though ion engines taking advantage of the imperfect vacuum of low orbit has been proposed.
- Large powerful first stage engines, as their power are wasted on the very modestly sized payload we can currently get into orbit.

Comment: I suspected there was an electrical method in addition to propellant and combustion, but I didn't know what it would be called to search for it. Thank you for identifying those terms.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Has ion propulsion ever been used in a deep space trajectory correction maneuver proper?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55954/12102)

Comment: @DanSorensen, you're probably thinking of an [electrodynamic tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether).